# Can I set value of input type to twig variable?

Tags: twig, timber

I need to set value of input type hidden to my twig variable:

```
<input type="hidden" name="question_index" value="0">
```

Twig variable in .twig file:

```
{% set index = "here I need to get question_index value" %}
```

Is that even possible, please?

Comment: Depends on when you want to get that value?

Comment: when page is loaded, then I know how to change input type value in JS and automatically timber variable will have value of input type

Comment: Then it's not possible. `timber`/`twig` is already executed before the output is sent to the client. It cannot interact with `javascript`. As you don't mention why you need to set the variable from `JS` to `twig`, it's hard to help you out but you probably want to send the value back to `timber` with e.g. ajax

Comment: yes something like that, thanks anyway. You helped me!